# GZIP decompression code throwing exception

Tags: java, exception, gzip, compression

Trying to decompress a gzip encoded http response. Passing the following to the decompressor:

```
gd.decompressGZIP(response.split("\r\n\r\n")[1].getBytes());
```

This code splits the response and sends the latter part(gzip encoded content) to the decompressGZIP function. The "response" variable is a String which contains the full htpp response. The decompresser code is as follows.

```
String decompressGZIP(byte[] gzip) throws IOException {
    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream bytein = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(gzip);
    java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream gzin = new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(bytein);
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream byteout = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int res = 0;
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    while (res >= 0) {
        res = gzin.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        if (res > 0) {
            byteout.write(buf, 0, res);
        }
    }
    return (new String(byteout.toByteArray()));
}
```

However, I am getting an exception as follows:

```
Sep 03, 2013 9:19:04 PM ownproxy.ProxyThread2 run
SEVERE: null
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:78)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:90)
    at ownproxy.GZIPDecompress.decompressGZIP(GZIPDecompress.java:18)
    at ownproxy.ProxyThread2.run(InterceptionProxy2.java:84)
```

The data seems not to be in gzip format. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried writing the bytes directly to a file and opening it with GZIP file manager?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to decode an http response by hand to extract the response body. Why not use the built-in apis to do that part for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to decompress text converted to bytes as a GZIP compressed stream and it is not.  When you encoded binary as text, it is usually mangled and information is lost which cannot be recovered.

A GZIP stream has a specific header and a CRC32 check sum at the end.  Without these it is not a valid format.

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

When you convert binary to text and back again, you don't get what you started with.  Don't do this.  You must keep the binary as binary and not convert it to text.

Comment: What would I do to make changes to the original response?